# Sorting data frame based on column value

Tags: python, pandas

I have column `col1` in the data frame with following values:

```
col1   col2  col3
9.1
9.1
9.11
9.12
9.13
9.14
9.15
9.16
9.2
9.3
9.4
9.5
9.6
9.7
9.8
9.9
10.1
10.1
10.2
10.3
```

Is it possilbe to sort data frame based on `col1` values as follows:

```
col1   col2  col3
9.1
9.2
9.3
9.4
9.5
9.6
9.7
9.8
9.9
9.10
9.11
9.12
9.13
9.14
9.15
9.16
10.1
10.1
10.2
10.3
```

There are two things here:

1. `9.10` is interpreted as `9.1` which I want avoid.
2. I want `9.10` appear after `9.9` in sort order.

Here is example code:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.DataFrame([9.1,9.7,9.8,9.9,9.10,10.0,10.1,10.2,10.11])
       0
0   9.10
1   9.70
2   9.80
3   9.90
4   9.10
5  10.00
6  10.10
7  10.20
8  10.11

>>> df.sort_values(0)
       0
0   9.10
4   9.10
1   9.70
2   9.80
3   9.90
5  10.00
6  10.10
8  10.11
7  10.20
```

I wanted it to be:

```
       0
0    9.1
1    9.7
2    9.8
3    9.9
4   9.10
5   10.0
6   10.1
7   10.2
8  10.11
```

I am ok if the it shows two digits after decimal point like `9.70`, but the order should be same.

**PS:** I didnt specify any column type as I am ok with any. My goal is to achieve two points specified above. This column values are actually directory names which I am loading in data frame and trying to sort in the order I specified above.

Comment: What's the `dtype` of `col1`? I don't see any value as `9.10` in your sample data..

Comment: @Rnj `9.1` and `9.10` are essentially the same. I think what you need to do is to have the data as `9.01` in your input

Comment: @ShubhamSharma I didnt specify any column type as I am ok with any. My goal is to achieve two points specified above. This column values are actually directory names which I am loading in data frame and trying to sort in the order I specified above. `9.10` is loaded as `9.1` itself thats why its not there in the first list. I have added the code example at the end of question.

Comment: You say "I want `9.10` appear after `9.9` in sort order." 
The only way to achieve this is to sort descending.

Comment: @SuhasMucherla I cant change the data. I have huge number of pre-named directories with names `9.1` and `9.10` which I am loading into pandas data frame.

Comment: Hey, please let me know if my answer is useful :)

Answer (score 2):

You must create the dataframe with `str` data (I shuffled it randomly):

```
data = ['9.1', '10.1', '10.2', '10.11', '9.8', '10.0', '9.10', '9.7', '9.9']
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['col1'])
#    col1
#0    9.1
#1   10.1
#2   10.2
#3  10.11
#4    9.8
#5   10.0
#6   9.10
#7    9.7
#8    9.9
```

Now, you can split the column:

```
new = df['col1'].str.split('.', expand = True)
#    0   1
#0   9   1
#1  10   1
#2  10   2
#3  10  11
#4   9   8
#5  10   0
#6   9  10
#7   9   7
#8   9   9
```

Add `new` columns to `df` and sort it following them. Remember 'new' contains 'str' instances, so you can cast them to `int` so you can compare values (in order to sort the dataframe):

```
df['num0'] = new[0].astype(int)
df['num1'] = new[1].astype(int)

df = df.sort_values(['num0','num1'])
#    col1  num0  num1
#0    9.1     9     1
#7    9.7     9     7
#4    9.8     9     8
#8    9.9     9     9
#6   9.10     9    10
#5   10.0    10     0
#1   10.1    10     1
#2   10.2    10     2
#3  10.11    10    11
```

**Optional**

If you don't want to keep the columns `num0` and `num1`, change the last code line for:

```
df = df.sort_values(['num0','num1'])['col1']
```

You can also reset the dataframe index with:

```
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df.col1 = df.col1.astype(float)
df = df.sort_values(by='col1')
```

Comment: Why convert `col1` to float when the OP may not want this?

Comment: I didnt specify any column type as I am ok with any. My goal is to achieve two points specified. This column values are actually directory names which I am loading in data frame and trying to sort in the order I specified.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
data = [9.1, 9.1, 9.11, 9.12, 9.13, 9.14, 9.15, 9.16,9.2,9.3,9.4,9.5,9.6,9.7,9.8,9.9,10.1,10.1,10.2,10.3,]
df = pd.DataFrame([[i,"",""] for i in data], columns=["col1", "col2", "col3"]).astype("str")

df.sort_values(by=['col1'], key=lambda x: [(int(i[0]), int(i[-1])) for i in x.str.split(".")], )
```